# I want to create multi page form for my complext dataclass and convert them map or list and send to firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, bloc, flutter-bloc

ı want to create step by step form but ı cant make it ı have been strugling about 2 weeks. Fİrst of
ı want to creat screen like in the left.
I will bring a different form to the screen according to the option selected at first. It can also be a page with dropdownbuttons, it can also be a menu with a texteditingcontroller form . And in the last step,I want to send the data I have received from different forms to send to firebase.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzZx6.jpg)

ı want to create step by step form but ı cant make it ı have been strugling about 2 weeks. Fİrst of
ı want to creat screen like in the left.
I will bring a different form to the screen according to the option selected at first. It can also be a page with dropdownbuttons, it can also be a menu with a texteditingcontroller form . And in the last step,I want to send the data I have received from different forms to send to firebase.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzZx6.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQkXX.png) ı try to create bloc pattern but ı couldnt

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: but i was not about the coode ı couldnt the structure